# Did upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 break the c++ linker?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, cmake

I have a Linux-based application, running under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, that compiled, linked, and ran with no problem.

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu to 14.04 LTS and encountered problems compiling and linking the app.

The compilation problems were solved by manually modifying my local copy of Boost 1.48 in two files (*include/boost/config/stdlib/libstdcpp3.h*pp and *include/boost/thread/xtime.hpp*).  At this point the app compiled successfully.

The problem I have is that the linkage fails with the error message:

```
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wl’
```

I use CMake to enable compiling the app on multiple platforms.  Here is the linker script generated by CMake.  Note that the "-Wl" options are now inexplicably unrecognized by /usr/bin/c++:

```
/usr/bin/c++ 
-fno-stack-protector 
-g 
-Wl 
CMakeFiles/Project.dir/main.cpp.o 
CMakeFiles/Project.dir/TestCallback.cpp.o 
CMakeFiles/Project.dir/utils.cpp.o 
CMakeFiles/Project.dir/Request1.cpp.o 
CMakeFiles/Project.dir/Response1.cpp.o 
CMakeFiles/Project.dir/TextChatRequest.cpp.o 
CMakeFiles/Project.dir/TextChatResponse.cpp.o 
-o 
/home/user/private/Project/Project_Release_1_2_Codename/Build/bin/Debug/Project 
-L/home/user/Libraries/Ubuntu32_12.04/boost_1.48/lib 
-L/home/user/Libraries/Ubuntu32_12.04/SqlLite_3.6/lib 
-L/home/user/Libraries/Ubuntu32_12.04/taglib_1.7/lib 
-L/home/user/Libraries/Ubuntu32_12.04/JSON_1.0/lib/Debug 
-L/home/user/private/Project/Project_Release_1_2_Codename/Build/../lib/libUbuntu32/Debug 
-rdynamic 
/home/user/private/Project/Project_Release_1_2_Codename/lib/libUbuntu32/Debug/libAPI.a 
/home/user/private/Project/Project_Release_1_2_Codename/lib/libUbuntu32/Debug/libInternals.a 
-lboost_thread 
-lboost_system 
-lboost_filesystem 
-lboost_program_options 
-ltaglib 
-lJSON 
-lpthread 
-Wl,-Bstatic 
-lsqlite3 
-Wl,-Bdynamic 
-ldl 
-Wl,-rpath,/home/user/Libraries/Ubuntu32_12.04/boost_1.48/lib:/home/user/Libraries/Ubuntu32_12.04/SqlLite_3.6/lib:/home/user/Libraries/Ubuntu32_12.04/taglib_1.7/lib:/home/user/Libraries/Ubuntu32_12.04/JSON_1.0/lib/Debug:/home/user/private/Project/Project_Release_1_2_Codename/Build/../lib/libUbuntu32/Debug
```

Here is version information for the software I'm using:

```
Ubuntu:
    14.04.1 LTS (trusty)

c++ compiler/linker:
    (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

CMake:
    Version 2.8.12.2
```

Why doesn't the linker recognize "-Wl" commands?  Did my upgrade to 14.04 LTS modify the linker software libraries?  How can I get my app back up and linking?

Comment: Make sure you completely remove all cmake-related files; `cmake` remembers completely retarded things in its cache file.

Comment: I think we need to see your full, exact linker command line.

Answer (score 5):

On line 4 of the command you have `-Wl` without any actual linker options.

https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/porting_to.html

Right at the top of this page is the following:

> Earlier releases did not warn or error about completely invalid
>   options on gcc/g++/gfortran etc. command lines, if nothing was
>   compiled, but only linking was performed. This is no longer the case.
>   For example,
>
> gcc -Wl -o foo foo.o -mflat_namespace
>
> Now produces the following error
>
> error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wl’
>
> error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mflat_namespace’
>
> Invalid options need to be removed from the command line or replaced by something that is valid.

12.04 LTS packaged GCC 4.6, you've now jumped to 4.8 and `-Wl` on its own is no longer a valid option (or rather it never was, GCC is just more pedantic now).

Comment: I don't really understand this answer...the OP did not pass `-Wl` by itself, it was `-Wl,-rpath,...` which seems valid in a linker command.

Comment: @JohnZwinck There's a naked `-Wl` on the fourth line.

Comment: To all: I modified the linker command, splitting the lines to make it more readable in StackOverflow.  The original linker command was one long single line with a horizontal scroll bar.  The "-Wl" options all had their expected parameters following them.  I'm out of the office and will only return next week so I cannot post the precise one-line linker command.

Comment: @MosheRubin What does the `-Wl` command on the 4th line look like in your original file?

Comment: @user657267 Since the linker command fit into a single line in StackOverflow with a horizontal scroll bar, just remove all newlines from what I posted.

Comment: @MosheRubin As above, `-Wl` is not a valid linker command, it has to be followed by a comma and one or more linker options. You do not need to pass your objects to the linker explicitly, GCC will do that automatically.

Comment: @user657267 So the command subsegment "-Wl CMakeFiles/Project.dir/main.cpp.o [...] CMakeFiles/Project.dir/TextChatResponse.cpp.o -o /home/user/foobar" is invalid because there is no command between the "-Wl" and the first *.o file?  This is the way the CMake linker command was generated.

Comment: @MosheRubin I don't use CMake so I can't help you there, but you should find it works if you get rid of that first `-Wl`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others previously, it indeed turned out that my CMake script was injecting a lone, solitary, seemingly unnecessary "-Wl" via the CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS setting:

```
if(LINUX)
   set(THIRDPARTY_LIBS boost_thread boost_system boost_filesystem boost_program_options taglib JSON)
   set(OS_LIBS  pthread sqlite3.a dl)
   set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl")
   set(PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS ${PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS};/DTAGLIB_STATIC)
endif(LINUX)
```

When I removed this setting, the build succeeded.  This oversight has been around a while, with the earlier version of gcc not minding.  The latest gcc, however, is more pedantic and flagged it as an error.